# Plugin in crm 2016

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2016

I have created a plugin for retrieving multiple attachments from Note entities of CRM .i have registered the plugin to my CRM Account but it is giving the following Error while i m trying to enter a Note or any file in my CRM Account.

Error : **This workflow job was canceled because the workflow that started it included an infinite loop. Correct the workflow logic and try again. For information about workflow logic, see Help.**
Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

The design you have implemented is resulting in an excess of executions resulting in CRM's inifinite loop detection functionality being tiggered and generating an error. You would need to post more about the design and provide the code for further assistance.

Via the [SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iexecutioncontext.depth.aspx):

> Every time a running plug-in or Workflow issues a message request to the Web services that triggers another plug-in or Workflow to execute, the Depth property of the execution context is increased. If the depth property increments to its maximum value within the configured time limit, the platform considers this behavior an infinite loop and further plug-in or Workflow execution is aborted.
>
> The maximum depth (8) and time limit (one hour) are configurable by the Microsoft Dynamics CRM administrator using the PowerShell command Set-CrmSetting. The setting is WorkflowSettings.MaxDepth. For more information, see, “Administer the deployment using Windows PowerShell” in the Deploying and administering Microsoft Dynamics CRM.

Comment: @varshanaithani where? Please don't post it as a comment. Please edit your original question to show your code.